# Permission 'See CiviCRM is installed' keeps being removed on Joomla

Tags: joomla, security

I have a problem where the CiviCRM permissions on a Joomla site keep being altered.  The 'See CiviCRM is installed' permission is set on 'Registered' users to 'Allowed' but keeps being reset to 'Not Allowed'.  Any suggestions as to what might be causing this would be appreciated - could it be a CiviCRm security check process running something?

PHP version 7.3.24, Joomla! 3.9.19 Stable, CiviCRM 5.31.0

Answer (score 0):

There is a paid Joomla component PWT ACL that helps a lot with these kind of problems.
For instance: the 'See CiviCRM is installed' permission could be the right to view the component with all contacts etc. This view of the component is only possible from the admin area of the website. To view it you need the right to login, you need to login at website.ext/administrator, and only then you can see the component as such.
If your registered user does not have the right of access to the admin area this right to See CiviCRM is not permitted, even if you explicitly set it like that: because the system does not allow access to the admin area, it cannot give access to the CiviCRM component when this requires access to the admin area first.

PWT ACL helps solve conundrums that can exist with 'clashing rights settings'.

Comment: I have used PWT ACL previously but in this case it wouldn't help.  The problem is that all users with admin access logging in to the backend lose the ability to see the CiviCRM component because the 'See CiviCRM is Installed' permission is randomly reset. Something in code is resetting to 'Not Allowed' no other permissions are being changed.

Comment: I am also seeing this on Joomla 3.9.24 and civi 5.31.0 ... 

I set my permissions so users have civiCRM: Extension: Access enabled. And then without any user intervention, the permission gets set to Access disabled.